# SSL Certificates for io.netty HTTP server

Tags: java, rest, ssl-certificate, netty, jersey-2.0

I am using org.glassfish.jersey and io.netty to create HTTP servers

For security reasons I want to protect my servers with SSL certificate.

This is my snippet code to create HTTP server:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(RestController.class);
Channel server=NettyHttpContainerProvider.createHttp2Server(URI.create(uri),
resourceConfig,null);
```

How can I add SSL certificate to my HTTP server ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variations of createServer method. One with [SslContext](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/netty-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/netty/httpserver/NettyHttpContainerProvider.java#L93-L94)
and another [without SslContext](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/netty-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/netty/httpserver/NettyHttpContainerProvider.java#L145-L146).
You can create SslContext and pass in the method.